# Function to get char and compare it with a token

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

So what I'm trying to do is a function where I receive a `char line[ ]` (this string is get from `fgets` a file in other function) and what I want is to count the number of times that a certain token appears in the string. The thing is that it's always giving me the error `Comparison between pointer and integer` and I don't know where the pointer is in my code.

Here is my code:

```
int validaString(char line[ ]){
    int i=0, j=0;   
    while (line[i] != "\n"){
        if(line[i] == "-" || line[i]== " ")
            j++;
        i++;
    }
    if(j==4)
        return 0;
    else 
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: You have a potential undefined behavior in your code (when it's fixed): What if there is no newline in the text? It can happen if the last line in the file doesn't end with a newline, or if the buffer you provide to `fgets` is not big enough to contain the whole line.

Comment: I though about that but the txt contains always the same lines type and my buffer is allocated dynamically

Answer (score 9):

`"\n"` is a string. Use `'\n'` to have a character literal. Same for `"-"` and `" "`.

Comment: C does not directly compare strings... thus strcmp(). You can compare chars, thus '\n'. You may also find strpbk() interesting.